# New particles found using the LHC

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

After finding the Higgs boson in 2012, CERN. What did the CERN found recently using the large Hadron Collider?

Comment: The purpose of LHC isn't just to discover new particles, but also to study the properties of the already found ones. For example, the analysis of the found Higgs' boson (i.e. into what substituents, with what frequency it decays) is still to be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a (partial?) list of new hadrons discovered at LHC experiments

$\chi_b(3P)$: a $b\overline{b}$ bound state, discovered by ATLAS in 2011

$\Xi_b(5945)^0$: a $bsu$ bound state, discovered by CMS in 2012

$\Xi_b^\prime(5935)^-$ and $\Xi_b^\star(5955)^-$: $bsd$ bound states, discovered by LHCb in 2014

$P_c(4380)$ and $P_c(4450)$: $c\overline{c}uud$ bound states, discovered by LHCb in 2015

Answer (score 4):

Recent particles, which were confirmed by CERN, are [pentaquarks](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/209919-cerns-large-hadron-collider-confirms-newest-particle-the-pentaquark) and also it has been observed that the [Bs0 meson](http://www.sci-news.com/physics/science-cern-bs0-meson-02800.html) decay in 2 muons. Both of these though had been theoretically predicted long ago.

Comment: As a matter of vocabulary, I would say they were predicted. Particle aren't know until they are found experimentally. If course  penta-quark statea have a more complicated history; they've been announced as discovered and then retracted previously. Also, it isn't *the* pentaquark, just the first example of that class confirmed; last time round they called it $\theta$, I think.

Comment: Your answer is not totally correct: the Bs0 meson was already knows since a while (~2 decades). What's new is the observation of its decay into 2 muons, which is very rare.

Answer (score 3):

The Large Hadron collider was closed for a year and more for an upgrade in energy from 7 to 14 TeV. They have started runs in the summer but there is nothing solidly announced, though there are some [exciting hints](http://motls.blogspot.gr/2015/09/cms-29-tev-electron-positron-pair.html) , which  need more statistics.